# I want to hide the label in a tooltip because it shows undefined

Tags: chart.js, linechart

I am using chart.js to show a line chart. How can I hide a tooltip label for a  chart.js line chart? The label in the tooltip is showing `undefined` so I want to hide the label (please see the screenshot)?

Perhaps there is a way to modify tooltip where I can show only the legends value in tooltip? My code is as follows:

```
  myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
      type: 'line',
      responsive: true,
      scaleShowGridLines : false,
      bezierCurve : false,
      animationEasing: "linear",
      tooltipEvents: ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove"],
      showTooltips: true,
      scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.8)",
  });
```

[image]

Comment: I want to hide the label only in tootlip is there any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the `tooltipTitleFontSize` to `0` in your options.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    ...
    tooltipTitleFontSize: 0
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I am using v2.7.1, is there any other way to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late, but I guess it still has merit to add this one.

check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632748/12061669

It uses a function to hide the title:

```
options:{
   tooltips:{
     callbacks:{
        title: ()=>{}
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the title's font size to zero is *not ideal* as you will still see an (ugly) extra space on top of the tooltip, as if the title line is still there - which honestly is what you'd expect.

Instead, I used Yumin Gui's answer but had to return `null` for it to work:
`

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    title: () => null,
  },
},
```

The result is *exactly* as in the pie charts (which does not have a title in its default tooltips).

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that worked, it's important that something is returned even null and therefore this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the tooltip title/label, it should be added in the options object for that chart as follows:

```
options: {
   plugins: {
      tooltip: {
         callbacks: {
            title : () => null // or function () { return null; }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Do refer to the documentation to understand better that it should be handled with a custom callback function, and it is not a config that can be set in options directly.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer won't work in newer versions of chart.js, as Aman said in comments, what you can use now is this:

```
tooltips: { titleFontSize: 0 }
```

Example:

```
var bar_chart = document.getElementById('bar_canvas').getContext('2d');
window.myBar = new Chart(bar_chart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: bar_chart_data,
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            titleFontSize: 0,
            bodyFontSize: 14,
        }
    }
});
```