# How do you hide the title of a chart tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using chart js to show grouped bar chart and try to hide the title of the tooltip

Code to generate bar

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Blue",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [3,7,4]
        },
        {
            label: "Red",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            data: [4,3,5]
        },
        {
            label: "Green",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            data: [7,2,6]
        }
    ]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        barValueSpacing: 20,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

In the tooltip it showing the labels Chocolate,Vanilla,Strawberry and i have tried to hide the label with following

by setting the titlefontsize to 0 but it doesnt work

```
tooltipTitleFontSize: 0
```

and i have tried with the tooltip callbacks it disables the label blue,red,green but i wont need that

```
 tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
           label: function(tooltipItem) {
                  return tooltipItem.yLabel;
           }
        }
    }
```

Help me thanks in  advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431733/i-want-to-hide-the-label-in-tooltip-because-it-showing-undefined

Comment: i have tried that but it doesnt work

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To hide the title of tooltip, you need to return an empty function on tooltips title­*'s* callback, like so ...

```
options: {
   tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
         title: function() {}
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi I get an error  `Types of property 'title' are incompatible.` I put it as you mentioned inside callbacks

Comment: The function needs to return *something*. Just return `null` and it should work. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62190418/756458

Comment: Chart.js 4.4, need to return empty string.

Answer (score 10):

To hide the tooltip title/label, it should be added in the options object for that chart as follows:

```
options: {
   plugins: {
      tooltip: {
         callbacks: {
            title : () => null // or function () { return null; }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Do refer to the documentation to understand better that it should be handled with a custom callback function, and it is not a config that can be set in options directly. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

I've mentioned the same in this other thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68033933/8578337

Comment: This method is more accurate otherwise eslint gives the this error. 
`Unexpected empty method 'title'.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function` -- click for detail [link](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-empty-function/)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Chart.js 4.3.1 documentation for [Tooltip Callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.1/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks):

> If the callback returns undefined, then the default callback will be used. To remove things from the tooltip callback should return an empty string.

```js
{
    options: {
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                // ...other options
                callbacks: {
                    title: () => ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```